# Is there a way to get the sum of non-zero elements in numpy array? I keep getting a TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

I googled this question extensively and I can't figure out what's wrong. I keep getting:

"TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'".

I searched it and the websites led me to download a package and that still didn't solve my issue. My code looks as follows:

```
result=[]
FracPos = np.array(result)
for x in lines:
    result.append(x.split())
TotalCells = np.array(result)[:,2]
print(type(TotalCells))
print(type(FracPos))
FracPos = np.sum((TotalCells)>0)
```

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-0972db6a45c4> in <module>
     17 TotalCells = np.array(result)[:,2]
     18 print(type(TotalCells))
---> 19 FracPos = np.sum((TotalCells)>0)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'
```

I can't figure out why I get the error at the last line and how to change it. I am very new to Python so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but the other questions like this are about nympy.ndarray and strings or lists which I understand why you can't compare.

Answer (score 0):

It is because result is a `list` containing `str` objects. If you only have numbers in your array, then do:

```py
result = [float(x) for x in result]
TotalCells = ...
```

Then, in order to get the sum of positive elements, you would have to do:

```py
FracPos = np.sum(TotalCells[TotalCells > 0])
```

The line you wrote counts the number of postiive elements, it does not sum them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I pulled out the second column of result to TotalCells because that column only contains numbers, then changed the type to np.array. Or so I thought. I tried your method with a slight tweak where I used TotalCells = np.array([float(x) for x in TotalCells]) and that works perfectly now!

Comment: You effectively changed the ype to `np.ndarray`, but what matters here is the `dtype` attribute of the array, which is `'O'` when the array contains strings.

However, numpy does try to apply the `>` operator to each of these objects. Since you cannot apply this operator between strings and integers, the method used by numpy to compare an array and something else returns NotImplemented. When a method returns NotImplemented, you get this error.

Comment: Ah i see! Thanks so much. I was so confused because the type was ndarray which I thought meant it was all fine to go.